# "failed to open stream: FTP server reports 550" when accessing file on Microsoft FTP Service using wrapper

Tags: php, ftp, fopen

In PHP, you have [wrappers for ftp and ftps](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) to allow you access files on an FTP using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

I want to use the wrapper to download a file as a stream.

**My simplified code:**

```
// eg. $url = "ftp://username:password@server.com/directory-with-dash/file.mp3";
$url = 'ftp://' . urlencode($username) . ':' . urlencode($password) . '@' . $server . $path . '/' . $filename;
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('ftp' => array('resume_pos' => 0)));
$fin = fopen($url, 'r', false, $ctx);
```

**Error:**

> Warning: fopen(ftp://...@server.com/directory-with-dash/file.mp3): failed to open stream: FTP server reports 550 /directory-with-dash/file.mp3: The system cannot find the path specified. in /var/www/ftp.php on line 4

**More Info:**

- The same url works fine when used with [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) on the same machine.
- Using PHP's [FTP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) to download files works fine
- FTP server responds with `220 Microsoft FTP Service` and `215 Windows_NT`
- FTP server can handle passive mode
- Using `filesize($url);` results in `Warning: filesize(): stat failed for...`
- `allow_url_fopen` setting is `On`
- The same code worked fine against a different FTP-server, `215 UNIX Type: L8`

What might be causing the problem?

**Edit:**

I have noticed that the `Microsoft FTP Service` doesn't place you in the root folder when you connect to the FTP, but in a subfolder:

> /username

This subfolder must not be in the URL when you use `wget` or a web browser:

> ftp://username:password@server.com/username/directory-with-dash/file.mp3 // Not available in Chrome
>   ftp://username:password@server.com/directory-with-dash/file.mp3 // Works fine in Chrome

<strike>I have tried both urls in the PHP-code, but I get the same error still.</strike> (I typed it wrong)

Comment: I successfully made a connection to a different FTP-server. It seems it is something with `Microsoft FTP Service` that doesn't play well. Edited.

Comment: I assume _"The system cannot find the path specified"_ is returned by the server. Can you access the server logs to see what local path this request translates to?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, its seems to come from the FTP server. I have no access to the FTP server logs I am afraid. Maybe I can request them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the FTP server not connecting to root (`/`) but rather to a subfolder (`/username`).

Unlike Chrome and wget, the FTP wrapper in PHP seems to require to have the full path and not the relative path:

**For Chrome, wget, etc.:**

> ftp://username:password@server.com/directory-with-dash/file.mp3

**For PHP's FTP wrapper:**

> ftp://username:password@server.com/username/directory-with-dash/file.mp3