# PHP file_put_contents with ftp:// - "FTP server reports 550" error

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to write a file from one hosting account to another (same server) with the following code (credentials redacted):

```
$fn = 'foo.bar';
$ftp_user = 'user@mydomain.com';
$ftp_pass = 'my-pass';
$ftp_host = 'ip.xx.xx.xx';
$ftp_uri = 'ftp://'.$ftp_user.':'.$ftp_pass.'@'.$ftp_host.'/home/user/public_html/test_dir/'.$fn;
$content = 'asdq3ersesdf';
$options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
$stream = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents($ftp_uri, $content, 0, $stream);
```

But I get:

> > failed to open stream: FTP server reports 550 Can't check for file existence in...

I've verified the account credentials are correct.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042815/failed-to-open-stream-ftp-server-reports-550-when-accessing-file-on-microsoft) talks about the need in PHP to specify the full path to the dir, including account username. The path above is correct, i.e. `/home/user/public_html/test_dir`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505357/getting-ftp-server-reports-550-could-not-get-file-size-when-using-ftp-url-in) says something about having to set file size, but that question is about reading, not writing.

What am I doing wrong?

[[UPDATE]]

Interestingly, everything works fine if I use PHP's dedicated FTP funcs e.g. `ftp_put()`, just not via the protocol.

Comment: Does the file your trying to write exist?  If so is it read only?

Comment: Doesn't exist..

Comment: Have you tried an interactive ftp program (i.e. filezilla), see how that copes?

Comment: Yeah - it works fine in Filezilla. It even works fine if I use PHP's dedicated FTP funcs e.g. `ftp_put()`, just not via the protocol.

Comment: Do you have an access to server-side log?